# How do I create a SQL databaes with options from the command line

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to create a SQL 2005 database with the following options:

1. SIMPLE RECOVERY
2. AUTO_SHRINK ON
3. AUTO_CLOSE ON

What is the command to do this?  The docs on Microsofts site are somewhat vague on this issue.  They say:

```
ALTER DATABASE
{
  SET < optionspec > [ ,...n ] [ WITH < termination > ] 
}
```

whatever that means...

I have tried this, which fails:

```
CREATE DATABASE TESTX SET RECOVERY SIMPLE, AUTO_CLOSE ON;
```

and I tried something like this, which failed also:

```
ALTER DATABASE TESTX
{
    AUTO_CLOSE ON  
  | AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
  | AUTO_SHRINK ON 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. Seems decent enough.

Comment: You might want to leave your comment under Squillman's post so that he gets an alert and can then answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it for you (change the initial file sizes as desired):

```
CREATE DATABASE [TESTX] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TESTX', FILENAME = N'C:\Path\To\Data\TESTX_Data.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TESTX_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Path\To\Logs\Blah_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [TESTX] SET AUTO_CLOSE ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [TESTX] SET AUTO_SHRINK ON 
GO
```

I'm guessing that this is for a dev database since you want AUTO_SHRINK and AUTO_CLOSE on.  However, if I'm guessing wrong and this is for a production system then it's HIGHLY recommended you leave those options off as they are very detrimental to the performance of your database.

**EDIT:**
In response to your comment - no, you have to create the database and then alter it with your options.  Have a look at the [**Books Online entry for CREATE DATABASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061(SQL.90).aspx), it gives the complete syntax for this statement.  You can't set database options with CREATE DATABASE.  All of database options are set with [**ALTER DATABASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: The answer seems to be that the database needs to be created first and then you do alter statements afterwards. There isn't a way to do it in one command, or not that I can tell. Can anyone validate this fact?

Comment: @djangofan: see my edit.